# How do I extract a property value from an object called with .find()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this code in my function

```
let packName: string = respPack.find(a => {a.id == 'name_input'}).answer.replace(/ /,'_');
```

What I'm trying to do is find the object by matching the id and extract the value of it's answer property.  As of right now I'm getting an error telling me

> cannot read property answer of undefined.

Am I trying to do this the right way?  Here's the rest of my function so you can see what's going on.

```
saveResponses(){
    const respPack = this.ResponseList;
    const sendTarget: FirebaseObjectObservable<any> = this.afdb.object('/submissions');

    let dataLoad:{ [prop : string]: Array<any> } = {};
    let packName: string = respPack.find(a => {a.id == 'name_input'}).answer.replace(/ /,'_');

    respPack.forEach( a => {
        if(a.answer){
            let data = { question: a.question, answer: a.answer, id: a.id };
            dataLoad[packName].push(data);
        }
        else if(a.responses){
            let dataChunk = { question: a.question, id: a.id, responses: Array<any> }; 

            a.responses.forEach(resp => {
                let respChunk = { response: resp.response, value: resp.value, id: resp.id };
                dataChunk.responses.push(respChunk);
            });
            dataLoad[packName].push(dataChunk);
        }
    });

    sendTarget.set(dataLoad);
}
```

Comment: Can you use `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: What should occur if `packName` is `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an arrow function with `{}` you have to include `return`.

Eg:

```
a => {return a.id == 'name_input'}
```

Also, `find` will return `undefined` if no items are found, you'll have to deal with those cases.

Here is a complete example:

```
let packName: string = "";
let foundElement = respPack.find(a => {
                              return a.id == 'name_input';
                            });
if(foundElement){
    packName = foundElement.answer.replace(/ /,'_');
}
```

Or if you want to keep it one line.

```
let packName: string = ((respPack.find(a => a.id == 'name_input') || {}).answer || "").replace(/ /,'_');
```

Comment: Thanks. I found out I just needed to add `return` and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

yourArray.find(element) will retrun the element following is an example

find more about find()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries)); 
// { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

You have the issue in your find method calling

```
a => {return a.id == 'name_input'}
```

find more about arrow function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions